# @MatrixVariable Spring 3.2 return Null

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, url-routing

I'm using Spring 3.2.6 in order to learn the @MatrixVariable feature with a basic example.

I have coded this method to get the matrix variable from the URI :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/matrix/{paths}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView MatrixVariableExample(@MatrixVariable Integer age){
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("affichageMatrix");
    mv.addObject("age", age);
    return mv;
}
```

I use this URI : localhost:8080/SpringMVC-Maven/matrix/user;age=23

The value returned for the age variable is null, but I it should be 23

Answer (score 1):

Enable **Matrix Variables** in spring config file:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven enable-matrix-variables="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your code like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/matrix/{paths}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView MatrixVariableExample(@PathVariable String paths, @MatrixVariable Integer age){
    System.out.println(paths); //or do something with it, at your choice
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("affichageMatrix");
    mv.addObject("age", age);
    return mv;
}
```

And use URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC-Maven/matrix/user;age=23
```

Your variable `paths` should now contain string `user`, and `age` should be `23`. I guess you're not allowed to miss path parameters if you have already parametrized your request mapping.

Comment: @user3600061 Some questions: 1) Do you really enter the method (can be checked by debugger)? 2) What's with the variable `paths`?

Comment: Yes, the paths value is returned : paths = user

Comment: Ok, I have two more guesses: the original example from Spring tutorial used `int`, not `Integer`. This is unlikely to be important, but still worth trying. Second: you may want to specify path and matrix variable names: `@MatrixVariable(value="age", pathVar="paths")`

Answer (score 0):

To use matrix variable you have to enable Spring MVC framework to read matrix variable in your application.
You can do it using either XML notation or by java configuration

XML configuration:
By adding below configuration in dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<mvc:annotation-driven enable-matrix-variables="true"/>
```

Java Configuration:

```
public class AppInitializer  extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {AppConfig.class};
    }
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] {"/*"};
}}

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages= {"com.springmvc.test"})
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver resolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver=new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        resolver.setPrefix("/jsp/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");     
        return resolver;
    }
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        UrlPathHelper urlPathHelper=new UrlPathHelper();
        urlPathHelper.setRemoveSemicolonContent(false);
        configurer.setUrlPathHelper(urlPathHelper);
}}
```